# Imprimir resultado de um array em formato de lista php

Tags: php, array, arraylist

Tenho dois `arrays` em `php`, os quais eu comparo e crio uma terceira e quero imprimir essa diferença em uma lista.

Já tentei o `foreach`, mas esse método imprime uma lista enorme em `string`.

Esse é o meu código:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos ORDER BY IPS ASC ");

while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"];
        }

$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara);

foreach ($diferenca as $diferencas)
{
        $stringArrayF = $stringArrayF.$diferencas;
}       
echo $stringArrayF;
```

O resultado impresso sai:

```
192.168.0.1192.168.0.2192.168.0.3192.168.0.4192.168.0.5...
```

Eu gostaria de poder colocar esse resultado em um *select* html

```
<select><option value="$stringArrayF">$stringArrayF</option>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos "); 






while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
 $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"]; 
} 

$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara); 

?> 




<body>
<select>
<?php foreach ($diferenca as $diferencas) { 
 $stringArrayF = $stringArrayF.$diferencas; 
?> 

<option value="$diferencas"><?php echo $stringArrayF; ?></option> 

</body>


<?php } ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Corrigido kkk denovo , agora vai

Comment: Melhorou! Mas ficou assim   `<select>
<option value="192.168.0.100">192.168.0.100</option>  
<option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104</option>  
<option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105</option>  
</select>`  O problema está em separar os resultados do _ array_ por posição.

Comment: declararar antes o i = 0

nesse caso poderiamos no value troca para um i++,
tipo

option value = $diferenca

para
option value = $i;

i++;

compreendeu ?

Comment: Acredito que tenha mais a ver com imprimir cada posição separadamente, Acho que a iteração, com um _for_ não faria isso no _<select>_ Teria que ser em outro lugar :/.  Só não sei onde

Answer (score -1):

**Faça isso corrigido**

```html
$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos ORDER BY IPS ASC ");

while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"];
        }

$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara);


?>

<?php


foreach ($diferenca as $diferencas)
{

$stringArrayF = $stringArrayF.$diferencas;
?>

<select><option value="<?php $stringArrayF ?>">$stringArrayF</option>;


<?php        
}    

?>
```

Comment: Tá aparecendo assim   `<html>
<form>

<select><option value="192.168.0.100">192.168.0.100</option>
<select><option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104</option>
<select><option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105</option>
<select><option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105192.168.0.106">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105192.168.0.106</option>

</form>`

Comment: mande ai o codigo que tu atualizou, pra eu dar uma olhada.

Comment: >`$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos ");
 
  while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
 $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"];
        }
 
$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara);

?>
<?php  
foreach ($diferenca as $diferencas)
         {
           $stringArrayF = $stringArrayF.$diferencas;
?>


<select><option value="<?php $stringArrayF ?>"><?php $stringArrayF ?></option>';

<?php   
}    
?> 

</select>`

Comment: Corrigido, so veja os aspas ai, 


$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos "); 
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
 $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"]; 
} 

$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara); 

?> 


<?php foreach ($diferenca as $diferencas) { 
 $stringArrayF = $stringArrayF.$diferencas; 
 

?> 
<select><option value="<?php echo $stringArrayF; ?>"></option></select> 
<?php } ?>

Comment: Infelizmente, não mudou muito:
`<select><option value="192.168.0.100">192.168.0.100</option></select>  



<select><option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104</option></select>  



<select><option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105</option></select>  
`

Comment: agora vai, testei aqui,

Comment: O que eu acho que o problema está em separar cada posição do array em uma _<option>_ . Pus o _<select >_ no ínicio de tudo e apareceu somente uma combobox, mas o resultado ainda não está como deveria.

Comment: veja la, o corrigido 2 kkk, pq na verdade, o select tem que esta antes do for each,

pq na verdade ele estava, multiplicando o select

Comment: Isso a gente já tinha corrigido. O _foreach_ tá fazendo um progressão Aritimética olha só   **Posição 1**; **Posição 1 + Posição 2**, **Posição 1 + Posição 2 + Posição 3** e assim sucessivamente!  `<select>
<option value="192.168.0.100">192.168.0.100</option>
<option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104</option>
<option value="192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105">192.168.0.100192.168.0.104192.168.0.105</option>
</select>`

Comment: Sabe @vitor, não sei se deixei claro, mas são 3 _arrays_ . **$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara)**. O **$diferenca** eu transformo em _string_ com o foreach.

Comment: consegui esse resultado `<select>
<option value="192.168.0.10
192.168.0.100  
192.168.0.101  
192.168.0.102  
192.168.0.103  
192.168.0.104  
192.168.0.106  
192.168.0.107  
192.168.0.108 ..</option>
</select>
</form>`  com esse código: `  while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"];
         }
 



$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara);


 $ipdisponiveis  = implode("\n", $diferenca);
   




?>
<select>


<option value="<?php echo $ipdisponiveis; ?>"><?php echo $ipdisponiveis; ?></option>


</select>`

Comment: precisa de ajuda ainda ?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Vitor, mas a resposta do @Guilherme Corrêa Peralta, resolveu meu problema! Muitíssimo grato por sua ajuda, aprendi muito.

Answer (score -1):

Tente trocar seu foreach para este código:

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($diferenca as $value)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}       
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Muito bom @Guilherme Corrêa Peralta! Eu havia conseguido fazer a lista, mas sem o _value_ . `<select>
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos WHERE RORDER BY IPS ASC");
 
  while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $arrayip[ ] = $aux["IPS"];
  }

$diferenca = array_diff($arrayip, $arraycompara);

 
 $ipdisponiveis  = implode("</option>\n<option>"  , $diferenca);
   
?>

<option><?php echo $ipdisponiveis;?></option></select> ` Sua solução foi Genial!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Por favor marque minha resposta como aceita clicando no check ao lado esquerdo da resposta. Veja como e porque neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers